# Blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values . NGINX with PROXY server

Tags: nginx, cors

When I add a single Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in NGINX, it has two.
When I remove the add_header line, there is none. So IDK where the extra origin is being added.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name service.alloy.love;
    root /var/www/cybers-cafe/cybers-cafe-service/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    access_log /var/log/nginx/service.alloy.love/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/service.alloy.love/error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/alloy.love/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/alloy.love/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

#    location /static/ {
#        alias /var/www/cybers-cafe/static/;
#        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#    }

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:59595;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.alloy.love';
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }


    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

I tried removing

```
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://www.alloy.love';
```

but as i said it completely removes the header.

I tried adding

```
proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
```

but this also completely removes the header.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it removing the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` response header from the requested script and keeping it only as **Nginx directive**

In my case (**python** script) I removed from the `do_GET` and `do_OPTIONS` methods of the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class:

```
# send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ...)
```